# Box2D: sticky wall issue in pool game using wck

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I'm new to `Box2D`, I'm using World [Construction Kit](https://github.com/jesses/wck), and I have the following problem: The ball is sticking to walls at low velocity.

So I read a lot of threads talking about this issue and found that I have to change `b2_velocitytreshold` value to `0.0f` in `b2settings.as`.

So I opened this file and I can't see this value, instead [I see this](https://github.com/jesses/wck/blob/master/Box2DAS/Common/b2Settings.as) :

```
public static function get b2_velocityThreshold():Number {
    return mem._mrf(lib.b2Settings.b2_velocityThreshold);
}

public static function set b2_velocityThreshold(v:Number):void {
    mem._mwf(lib.b2Settings.b2_velocityThreshold, v);
}
```

So I don't know how to change this value...

I searched for hours now, but it's really hard for me because I'm not an English speaking person (I bet you noticed) and I only found one tutorial about `wck` in my language.

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post a link to the post where you found you should set the value of `b2_velocitytreshold` value to be  `0.0f`.

But as I understand it, you have here setter/getter for `b2_velocitytreshold`. So the solution to your proble can simply be changing the value return by the getter:

```
public static function get b2_velocityThreshold():Number {
   return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: This thread is talking about B2settings.h (I tried, nothing changed):
    http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12003/physics-engine-recommendation-which-can-simulate-pool-game-correctly

Comment: This one is talking about B2settings.as 

http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1405

Comment: Ok, then my solution should work. At least it is a way to change the value but it seems you'll have to find out what value is correct for your goal. You might also want to have a look at the class `CLibInit` and its `init()` method in `achacks.as`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Answer, I tried in a lot of way but didn't managed to make it work, so i found another solution.

I added a frame in the world component (2 frames now) :

First frame : LinearVelocity : 0.1
Second frame : LinearVelocity : -0.1

Balls doesn't stick now.

I know it is a "bad" solution, but I was tired of searching and testing every possible option, so this solution is good enough for me.

I will maybe figure how to use your solution in the future when I will learn more about Box2D.

Thank you again.